# Comparison in MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, comparison

Does MySQL make it possible to do something like:

`SELECT username, age, age>13 AS ageGT FROM users`.

And get something like:

```
+--------+---+-----+
|username|age|ageGT|
+--------+---+-----+
|fred    |14 |true |
|bob     |12 |false|
+--------+---+-----+
```

?

This would be a huge help, thanks!

Clarification: I'm not looking for a `WHERE` clause, I want to select both cases, but have a column showing whether the clause evaluates true or false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do `CASE WHEN age > 13 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS ageGT`:

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    age, 
    CASE WHEN age > 13 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS ageGT
FROM users
```

Or more simply:

```
IF(age>13, 'true', 'false') AS ageGT
```

Read more on [CASE Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and the [IF() Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

An important difference is that the `CASE` expression syntax is supported by all major DBMSs, whereas `IF()` is pretty much MySQL specific.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT username, 
age, 
case when age>13 then 'true' else 'false' end AS ageGT 
FROM users
```